# Unable to implement EDSDk for Android for canon camera integration?

Tags: android, edsdk

I am making an application i need to integration canon camera through Android device for i got sdk from canon provided for windows.. in which there are 3  headers files and EDSDK.lib  and some Dll files . I am using android NDK for integrating  c files in android Applications.
Please  help..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You really are not going to be able to use the Windows SDK for Android.

You will either have to find an Android SDK, build it yourself [ assuming the source of the SDK is available ], or reverse engineer the protocol.